# Word to describe unimaginative craft?

Tags: single-word-requests

Imagine a poet who spends too much time trying to stick to the meter, a writer who overuses purple prose, a musician who plays a piece well but without emotion, or a painter who is preoccupied with exactly replicating the reference.

Their creations would be technically advanced, but lacking in beauty.

What would be the word to describe those people or their work that acknowledges the "technically advanced" part?

Answer (score 1):

There is no single term.

We could talk of **perfunctory** perfomances for the musician.

For the painter  we might talk of an artist **(just) going through the motions** ([Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/go-through-the-motions)), or painting in a **mechanical** manner.

A poet's work characterized by the rigidity of the poetical form and a poor content could be characterized as an artist given to **sterile formalism**.

A poet whose workis characterized by the rigidity of the poetical form at the detriment of the content  can be said, among other things, **to be prisoner of his technique**.

Answer (score 1):

Workmanlike

"competent and skillful but not outstanding or original. an adequate … reporter who turned out workmanlike copy." Merriam Webster

Answer (score 0):

Both the creator of the piece and the resulting piece itself could be described as [**austere**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/austere):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>   **3** : markedly simple or unadorned
>        // an *austere* office
>        // an *austere* style of writing
>   **4** : giving little or no scope for pleasure
>        // *austere* diets

The artist (or the art) is technically proficient, but lacking in passion or any additional personal touches that would signal something truly individual or even creative.

Answer (score -2):

How about **technician**, used in a pejorative sense? From Lexico:

> **[technician](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/technician)**: A person skilled in the technique of an art or craft. E.g., ‘The junior leading men, admirable *technicians* to whom the notion of charisma is alien, don't appear destined for stardom.’

Dali, for example, was a superb **technician**, but many feel his art lacks soul. There are many good writers who are superb **technicians**, but who will never be great novelists. Etc. I have often seen and heard **technician** used in a derogatory sense to convey the idea that *So-and-so is highly skilled in the technique of their art or craft, but it ends there. They will never be great. There's something lacking. They are **mere** technicians.*